Kafka PLAINTEXT security cannt let client connect via APIVERSION_QUERY
i am starting out with kafka and have encountered an error:
I have setup a advertised_listener with plaintext and want to connect to it via the confluent c# client but upon trying to connect, i get the error "incorrect security.protocol configuration", even though i have configured the broker to use PLAINTEXT and set it in my client ?
my compose file can be run and kafka works with console prod/con and i tested the client with a redpanda kafka quickstart setup and was able to send and recv via the c# client
i am aware that i am starting out and that there is probably a lot of information already, maybe even for this specific topic, i hope you can maybe leave a comment with a link to it, so that i can look into it. i appreciate your help
localhost:19092/bootstrap: Enter main broker thread
localhost:19092/bootstrap: Received CONNECT op
localhost:19092/bootstrap: Broker changed state INIT -> TRY_CONNECT
localhost:19092/bootstrap: broker in state TRY_CONNECT connecting
localhost:19092/bootstrap: Broker changed state TRY_CONNECT -> CONNECT
 librdkafka v2.5.3 (0x20503ff) rdkafka#producer-1 initialized (builtin.features gzip,snappy,ssl,sasl,regex,lz4,sasl_gssapi,sasl_plain,sasl_scram,plugins,zstd,sasl_oauthbearer,http,oidc, SSL ZLIB SNAPPY ZSTD CURL SASL_SCRAM SASL_OAUTHBEARER PLUGINS HDRHISTOGRAM, debug 0x2)
localhost:19092/bootstrap: Connecting to ipv4#127.0.0.1:19092 (plaintext) with socket 1004
localhost:19092/bootstrap: Connected to ipv4#127.0.0.1:19092
localhost:19092/bootstrap: Connected (#1)
localhost:19092/bootstrap: Updated enabled protocol features +ApiVersion to ApiVersion
localhost:19092/bootstrap: Broker changed state CONNECT -> APIVERSION_QUERY
localhost:19092/bootstrap: Disconnected while requesting ApiVersion: might be caused by incorrect security.protocol configuration (connecting to a SSL listener?) or broker version is < 0.10 (see api.version.request) (after 1ms in state APIVERSION_QUERY) (_TRANSPORT)
localhost:19092/bootstrap: Disconnected while requesting ApiVersion: might be caused by incorrect security.protocol configuration (connecting to a SSL listener?) or broker version is < 0.10 (see api.version.request) (after 1ms in state APIVERSION_QUERY)
localhost:19092/bootstrap: Updated enabled protocol features -ApiVersion to
localhost:19092/bootstrap: Broker changed state APIVERSION_QUERY -> DOWN
localhost:19092/bootstrap]: 1/1 brokers are down

versions:
kafka 3.8.0
Confluent.Kafka 2.5.3
Docker version 27.2.1-rd, build cc0ee3e
C# code:
    public static async Task Main(string[] args){
        string role = args[0];
        string topic = args[1];
        string hostname = args[2];
        string port = args[3];
        switch (role) {
            case "producer": await Producer(topic,hostname,port); break;
            case "consumer": Consumer(topic,hostname,port);break;
            default: Console.WriteLine("Usage: \"producer\" or \"consumer\"");break;
        }
    }
    public static async Task Producer(string topic,string hostname, string port){
        var config = new ProducerConfig{
            BootstrapServers = hostname+":"+port,
            SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.Plaintext,
            BrokerAddressFamily = BrokerAddressFamily.V4,
            Debug ="broker",
            ApiVersionRequest = false,
        };
        using (var p = new ProducerBuilder<Null,string>(config).Build()){
            try{
                string msg = "Hello World";
                var dr = await p.ProduceAsync(topic,new Message<Null, string> 
                    {Value = msg}
                );
                Console.WriteLine($"Send: '{dr.Value}' to '{dr.TopicPartitionOffset}' ");

            }catch(ProduceException<Null,string>e){
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {e.Error.Reason}");
        }
    }

docker compose:
services:

  broker:
    image: apache/kafka:latest
    container_name: broker
    hostname: broker
    networks:
      - kafka-nw
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 19092:19092
    environment:
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 1
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: broker,controller
      #KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,CONTROLLER://localhost:9093
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092,HOST://localhost:19092,CONTROLLER://0.0.0.0:9093
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:19093,HOST://localhost:19092
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: CONTROLLER
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,HOST:PLAINTEXT
      #KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,HOST:SASL_PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: 1@localhost:9093
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS: 3
networks:
  kafka-nw:

I changed the ports around and used different host names and now i am trying to switch it to sasl_plaintext, in hope of it working now.
EDIT 04.11.2024:
Solved ! My Setup: Company Laptop -> Windows -> docker -> wsl -> kafka
As it turned out, Windows didnt register the necessary kafka ports in my docker compose, due to ... After a bit of restarting and using netstat commands and the such, it worked. (Nothing shown here was changed).
Can be considered closed, as the underlying code and the docker compose were correct.
